# How do I start a new blank image page in Preview?

Tags: macos, preview

I want to be able to paste an image in a new blank page in Preview.app but do not see this option in the program.

Answer (score 8):

This is a workaround I use that suffices since I rarely use Preview, so there may be better options than this.

Typically, when creating a new image in image editing software you'll be prompted for things such as resolution, background, etc. So I've created a bunch of default images I keep stored in a folder with descriptive filenames such as:

- 500x500 transparent image
- 500x500 white image
- 500x1000 transparent image
- and so on

On the rare occasion I have to start from scratch using Preview, I just open the image I need and do a Save As... (hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> as I click on the File menu or just use the <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> keyboard shortcut) and I'm good to go.

Comment: Very complete definition of the missing function of `Preview`. Try to sale it to Apple .

Comment: Well, Preview wasn't designed originally to *create* images, it was more about viewing, editing and converting images and PDFs. But I agree, it really should provide this feature as it certainly complements the rest of its functions.

Answer (score 4):

If you open a png image and, once its open, do a select all under the edit menu. After select all hit the delete key. This will leave a blank page that you can add to.  This will destroy you png file so be sure you have another copy of it.

Comment: This is the simplest answer for creating a one-off new blank image in Preview if you haven't planned ahead (like in @Monomeeth's answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer about opening a new, empty Preview page for an image. However you mentioned wanting to paste an image into Preview, I'm interpreting that as wanting a typical 8.5" x 11" page, with an image pasted into it. The following will work:

1. Double click on the image, which should open it in Preview **as an image**: [image: image in preview]
2. Print the image (command-P)
3. Save it as a PDF (lower left): [image: OS X print dialog]
4. This generates a regular PDF file, using the page size you specified in the OS X print dialog.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy an image and open the preview.app, you can press `cmd n` to open a new window with the content of the clipboard (File -> new from clipboard).

Alternatively you can drag and drop image(s) onto the preview.app symbol in the doc to open them in the preview.app.

Comment: Neither of these answer the question of how to create a new, *blank* image.

Comment: Yes, but the question is how to create a blank page **in order to paste an image into it**. This answer shows that it's a one-step process.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will result in your graphic in a Preview file (which is probably what you want. If not, tell us your end goal)

1. Copy (Command-C) the graphic
2. Open the Notes app
3. Paste (command-v) the graphic into the Notes app.
4. Double click the graphic in the Notes app.

The graphic will open in Preview, which will convert it to a PNG.
Give it a real name and save (default is a random long name)